# Formatting/markdown not being parsed when in HTML tags

Tags: support, hyperlinks, markdown

If I ask/answer a question, sometimes I like to include numbered lists using the `<ol>` and `<ul>` HTML tags. There is a problem, however, if I want to format the text to make it bold or italic using the `**bold**` and `_italic_` markdown formatting, in that it doesn't display properly when inside HTML tags. This problem is easily solved, as there are bold and italic buttons above the question textarea. The problem becomes unsolvable, however, when I want to post links inside the tags. Neither the `<a>` tag,  the hyperlink button, nor the markdown link methods work, and get parsed as plain text. Has anyone else noticed this, is stackoverflow working on it, and is there a solution?

Comment: Easy solution: use Markdown instead of HTML for your lists.

Comment: @animuson can you use markdown for lists, or other common formatting? Can you link a definitive list?

Comment: @imulsion [Yes, you can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184477/186381)

Comment: [Here's a list of markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can just [include links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184476/formatting-markdown-not-being-parsed-when-in-html-tags) in lists using entirely markup.

- Or you could just [use html](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184476/) and no markup
- It's only if you try to [mix them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184476/) that it doesn't work.

for reference, the markup of this post is:

```
- You can just [include links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184476/formatting-markdown-not-being-parsed-when-in-html-tags) in lists using entirely markup.

<ul><li>Or you could <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184476/">just use html</a> and no markup</li>
<li>It's only if you try to [mix them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184476/) that it doesn't work.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: uh.........how?

Comment: @imulsion I just demonstrated how...